# jquery expand/collapse all items

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jquery

I have a bunch of items which can be collapsed/exapanded individually by clicking on the icon.
I need to modify my code a little more. I need add another icon on top. When you click on that you can expand/collapse
all the below items at once. Can someone help me with that part?

Here is my javascript code

```
$(document).on('show hide', '#programs-accordion', function(e) {
  $(e.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

here is my haml code

```
#programs-accordion.accordion
  - @patient_summary.programs.each_with_index do |program, index|
    .accordion-group
      .accordion-heading
        .accordion-toggle.group-accordion-toggle
          %a{ href: "#collapse-#{index}", data: { parent: '#programs-accordion', toggle: 'collapse' }}
            %i.icon-plus
          %a= program.name
         .accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}", class: (@office.to_i == office.id) ? "" : "collapse" }
           .accordion-inner 
            - office.positions.each_with_index do |position, index|
              #measures-accordion.accordion
                .accordion-group
                  .accordion-heading
                    .row-fluid
                      .span2{class: "offices-#{position.status}"}= position.status
                      .span1= position.results.first.value
                      .span2= position.results.first.value_date_time.blank? ? '' : Date.parse(position.results.first.value_date_time)
                      .span5= position.name
```

EDIT: JS fiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle on jsbin/jsfiddle?

Comment: haml(?) code isn't much use. Please post the outputted HTML.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working here.

```
$('.expandcollapse').click(function() {

    $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
        $(this).collapse("toggle");
    });

    if ($(this).html() == "<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All") {
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
    }
    else {
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All");
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/6/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
 $('.expandButton').click(function() {
   $('.accordion-body').addClass('collapsed');
   $('.accordion-toggle i').removeClass('icon-plus');
   $('.accordion-toggle i').addClass('icon-minus');
 });
```